# Looping through a json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, foreach

I am trying to look through an object, but based on the structure I do not know how to get to the data.

Object:

```
{
"177":{
     "text":"test text",
     "user_name":"Admin",
     "date":"1385494358",
     "docs":{
        "document_name": [
            "marketing_service",
            "maintenance_service",
            "development_service"],
        "document_type":[
            "png",
            "png",
            "png"]
       }
},
"174":{
     "text":"Some more images",
     "user_name":"Admin",
     "date":"1385493618",
     "docs":{
        "document_name": [
            "marketing_service16",
            "maintenance_service53"],
     "document_type":[
            "png","png"]
      }
}
}
```

The loop I am attempting in jQuery

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
$(obj).each(function(index, note) {
    console.log(note.text + note.user_name + note.date_created);
});
```

It is returning undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `data` is it a string?

Comment: data is the object displayed in the above code

Comment: Please show exactly how you declare and set `data`. If `data` is already an object you don't want to use `$.parseJSON()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
for(var n in obj){
 var note = obj[n]
 console.log(note.text + note.user_name + note.date_created);
}
```

Comment: Basically what I said :-P

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a json object just use a for loop.

The way you are doing it will return errors because it is trying to select that json object from the page which does not exist.

Sample code:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data); //assuming `data` is a string
for(index in obj) {
    var note = obj[index];
    console.log(note.text + note.user_name + note.date_created);
};
```

Comment: You should be very careful using for in without checking the object has the property first.

Comment: What do you mean @DavidBarker ?

Comment: _"it is trying to select that json object from the page"_ - [No it isn't.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-object)

Comment: @qwertnl obj.prototype is a property of the object, as is obj.length. When using for in loops you need to check `if (object.hasOwnProperty(property))` before attempting to gather data from it.

Comment: I have never heard of that before @DavidBarker Do you have a source?

Comment: @DavidBarker: That's simply not true.

Comment: @DavidBarker - Using `.hasOwnProperty()` is generally a good idea, but where did you get `obj.prototype` and `obj.length` from? Objects don't automatically have a `.prototype` or `.length` property, but for objects that do wouldn't you expect to include `.length` in a loop over all properties?

Comment: Using `.hasOwnProperty` should only be used when it makes sense to use it. It doesn't make sense to use it as a broad guard on every single loop of every single object.

Comment: @steeped: The `docs` is just another property. If you're asking how to iterate it, you'd just test for it, and start another loop when that property is reached. Or just do a separate loop outside the main loop. Nested object traversal has been asked about many times on this site. I'm sure if you search, you'll find more than enough information.

Answer (score 0):

its a little better to do it like this:

```
$.each(obj, function ( index, note ) {
    console.log( note.text + note.user_name + note.date_created );
});
```

this should give you what you need

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gZ7pd/ **or** `for document` http://jsfiddle.net/NGqfB/

Issue is `parseJson` on the object which is Json.

in the demo above the `var obj = $.parseJSON(data);` returns null, if I use data it will work.

Hope this helps `;)`

**Code**

```
var data = {
"177":{
     "text":"test text",
     "user_name":"Admin",
     "date":"1385494358",
     "docs":{
        "document_name": [
            "marketing_service",
            "maintenance_service",
            "development_service"],
        "document_type":[
            "png",
            "png",
            "png"]
       }
},
"174":{
     "text":"Some more images",
     "user_name":"Admin",
     "date":"1385493618",
     "docs":{
        "document_name": [
            "marketing_service16",
            "maintenance_service53"],
     "document_type":[
            "png","png"]
      }
}
};

var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(obj)

$.each(data,function(index, note) {

    alert(note.text + note.user_name + note.date_created);
});
```

Comment: @Downvoter care to reply why a downvote?? `:)` or is it just personal choice to downvote? not constructive!

Comment: @kkemple Thanks bruvoo `:)` Its very sad some people downvote without any reason! Cheeerios yo! +1 to you!